Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS automatic updates
I'm very new to Linux. I have the GUI Software Updater set to install updates weekly. Is that sufficient for basic use? Is there any reason why I should need to use
sudo apt updates
sudo apt upgrade

or unattended-updates?

The default settings are intended to be sufficient for basic use.

Was the default not daily?
